# call function when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have simply js file but i can't call function with parameter
the code

```
function removetr(str){
$(".g"+str).val("");
$(".ga"+str).val("");
$(".gb"+str).val("");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.buttonno1").click( removetr(1) );
});
```

the class of inputs that i want to remove it's values are g1,ga1 and gb1

i want to note that if i change the code to

```
function removetr(){
str=1;
$(".g"+str).val("");
$(".ga"+str).val("");
$(".gb"+str).val("");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.buttonno1").click( removetr );
});
```

it's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to an event handler, your current code is calling the function directly. Either build your function as an event handler, or pass an anonymous function reference to the click handler.

<sub>as event handler:</sub>

```
function removetr(e) {
    var str;
    str = e.data.str;
    $(".g"+str).val("");
    $(".ga"+str).val("");
    $(".gb"+str).val("");
}

$(function () {
    $("input.buttonno1").click({str: '1'}, removetr);
});
```

<sub>as anonymous function reference:</sub>

```
function removetr(str) {
    $(".g"+str).val("");
    $(".ga"+str).val("");
    $(".gb"+str).val("");
}
$(function () {
    $("input.buttonno1").click(function () {
        removetr(1)
    });
});
```